# JetBrains xodus on android

Tags: android, kotlin, xodus

did anyone try xodus on android and got it working? I am talking about: https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus
Would love to get it working - but it seems to use some features that are not available on Android - wonder if there is a workaround to make it work. Stalling at:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(23040): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;
```

Comment: Please take a look at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/XD-655.

Comment: Thanks so much - would even accept this as an answer